# relative positioning of FAB button next to responsive profile picture

Tags: css, sass, ionic2

I would like to position a FAB (camera) next to profile picture (responsive). Since the profile picture's location changes based on screen size, I would like to calculate location of the button relative to the profile picture.

I tried this but the button is positioned all the way to the end of the photo.

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div  style="position:relative">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-avatar><img src="../../assets/AJ_pic.jpg" alt=""></ion-avatar>
            <button ion-fab mini color="primary" style="position:relative; bottom:0; right:0; transform: translate(0%, 0%);"><ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-item>
</div>
```

It should be like Whats'App interface.

FAB **should not be fixed position** since the page is scroll-able. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are right, I should have added the code that I tried. Just did that.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
position: absolute
```

Simple demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/5t49m2r8/

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The problem Im trying to solve is that the image is "responsive" so based on screen size, its location changes. What I really want to do is to position the button relative to the image itself. Do you know how that is possible?